# Adobe Flex 4.5 - single sourcing a web-client and a mobile-client - whats possible?

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3, mobile, flex4.5

I’m a Flex developer and I’m interested in porting existing flex 4.5 web application to a mobile devices.

The question is: Is it possible to single-source some code for the mobile-client and the web-client? Sure, the UI will differ a lot and it is likely that most stuff must be rewritten. Anyway, is it possible to write UI-Code that is runnable on both platforms (web and mobile)?

What possibilities do technically exist to setup that in Flash Builder (eclipse)?

On the other hand there is code that should be shared between the web- and the mobile-app that contains utility-methods and things like that. I guess for that it should be relatively easy to share the same code-base due a library-project or something like that – what do you think? What is the kind of project I have to setup for that – are there examples available for that use-case?

One last question: Are there any cool tools for flex-mobile give support for the problem of the not always available internet connection – working offline, syncing… I guess here it is important to note that I want to use a Java backend and none of these adobe-services.

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You definitely can.  There are no "tools" for it really, it's all about how to setup your project.  As Flextras said, you'd want to create a library that has all the code that can be shared between both mobile and web projects but you'd want a separate application for both since the layout would change quite a bit.

As for the components to be reusable, the default flex ones has a web and a mobile version, but if you're creating your own custom components, I recommend you create 2 different skins for each (which is what the flex sdk is doing automatically) which would be specified in the css theme of each project.  This way your component has the save functional code, but different looks.  Beware however for performance bottlenecks since phones aren't as powerful as desktops.  Frankly, just keep things simple on the mobile app and you should be good.

As for 'syncing' tools, there aren't any because it would be hard to have a baseline for projects because each project is different.  You can however use SQLite on the mobile project for offline data/syncing.  You'll have to implement that yourself, but it's really not that bad unless you have very convoluted business rules.

That's about it.  It's not rocket science but be sure to keep it simple.

Answer (score 0):

I feel like I answer this a lot, but couldn't find any previous answer, so...

I respect the need to want to reuse as much code as possible.  To do that I would recommend moving the shared code into a library project and using that same library project across all your different projects.

In theory you could do this with a complete application and your individual mobile project and web project only need the main application file; with all other code being in the library.  Practically, as you already stated, you wouldn't want to use the same UI on a web site compared to a native mobile app.